# What is the recommanded way to install Bazel on macOS?

Tags: macos, bazel

[Installing Bazel on Ubuntu](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/4.0.0/install-ubuntu.html)
says:

> Use Bazelisk (recommended)

[Installing Bazel on macOS](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/4.0.0/install-os-x.html) says:

> Use the binary installer (recommended)

Isn't Bazelisk the recommended way to install Bazel on macOS? Or is  [Installing Bazel on macOS](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/4.0.0/install-os-x.html) outdated?

Answer (score 1):

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL \
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

```
brew install bazel
```

```
brew upgrade bazel
```

its as simple as the site says

Comment: I am getting this error on step 2: 
Warning: No available formula with the name "bazel".
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.

Comment: @Notron Try installing using the binary installer [https://bazel.build/install/os-x#install-with-installer-mac-os-x/]

Comment: Hi @Seaver, it turns out that the problem was with brew, I solved this by running the command: "brew doctor".